# WebView in fragment is white

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, fragment

I'm new to this so I'm sorry if it is an obvious error. When my application runs the tab with a WebView returns nothing but white space. Does anyone see the fault?

Tab2.java:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url="http://google.co.uk/";
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);


    return v;
}

}
```

tab_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#424242">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try loading your webview in onActivityCreated

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
 public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

        public final static String TAG = Tab2.class.getSimpleName();

        public Tab2() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }



        public static Tab2 newInstance() {
            return new Tab2();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);



        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            final WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://google.co.uk/");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Loading WebView",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.txt");//show text file if no internet

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The difference between my code and your code is that I am using `onViewCreated` to load url you are using `onCreateView`.

And by the way, why are you using two inflaters to inflate same thing?

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have set the permission for accessing internet in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code. Hope it helps you - 
**Fragment** -

```
...
        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

                final WebView webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
                webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
                webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webview.loadUrl(URL);

        // Using to refresh webpage when user swipes the screen
                mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                webview.reload();
                            }
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });


                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                return rootView;
            }
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
...
```

And my **XML** is -

```
...
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
...
```

Also, don't forget to add **Manifest permission** -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```